# How to extract a list from an IActionResult

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm attempting to test the result from an API controller that returns an `IActionResult`. Currently it is returning an object with status code, value, etc. I'm trying to access just the value.

```
List<Batch.Context.Models.Batch> newBatch2 = new List<Batch.Context.Models.Batch>();
var actionResultTask = controller.Get();
actionResultTask.Wait();
newBatch2 = actionResultTask.Result as List<Batch.Context.Models.Batch>;
```

`actionResultTask.Result` returns a list including a list "Value" which is a list of `Batch.Context.Models.Batch` and I cannot access this value. It turns to *null* after casting it to a list.

This is the controller

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(404)]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<Batch.Context.Models.Batch>))]
[Route("Batches")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var myTask = Task.Run(() => utility.GetAllBatches());
    List<Context.Models.Batch> result = await myTask;

    return Ok(result);

}
```

How do I access the value as a list.

Comment: I've not done this with .net core, but I would imagine that similarly to webapi2, the interface `IActionResult` is a wrapper around the data you are returning. So it's an object that contains relevant headers, status codes, and the content. In webapi2, you would deserialise the response.Content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because the `Result` of the `Task` is an `IActionResult` derived class, `OkObjectResult`

Make the test async. Await the Method under test. Then perform the desired assertions.

For example

```
public async Task MyTest {

    //Arrange
    //...assume controller and dependencies defined.

    //Act
    IActionResult actionResult = await controller.Get();

    //Assert
    var okResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(okResult);

    var newBatch = okResult.Value as List<Batch.Context.Models.Batch>;
    Assert.IsNotNull(newBatch);

    //...other assertions.
}
```